# Best up-to-date method for quering SCVMM 2012 R2 via C# and PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

Microsoft points you to use PowerShell to manage and query VMM. There is so many examples out there for using PS within c#, none point out what is the latest or for what version of PS the example code is for. We are using what we found to work with VMM from our code, but it seems to be VERY poor when it comes to memory consumption. Doing a simple list of VMs in a cloud causes the app to grow almost 300mb! And it just sits there, sometimes grows to even more. We are making all the proper dispose and object clean up as much as we can. I just believe that using PS from within c# does not seem to be a very good approach. I feel if there where a SDK with API calls it would use much less ram.

With the current version of PS released today, 4.0, what is the most efficient way of calling PS commands from within C#? If you want a sample PS command we call as an example, you can use the below: This lists all VMs within a cloud.

```
Get-SCVMMServer -ComputerName 'vmmserver' -Credential $cred | Get-SCCloud -Name 'cloud name' | Get-VM
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently wrestling with the exact same memory issue. However, I think I have a solution -- currently in the mists of putting it through its paces right now so I am not sure if the posted solution is the best or final solution. My environment is Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter and SCVMM 2012 R2.

Here are my findings

Given the following script running in a loop or just being called over-and-over

```
If (-Not(Get-Module -Name VirtualMachineManager)) {
    Import-Module -Name VirtualMachineManager
}

[Hashtable]$return = @{}

$vmm = Get-VMMServer -ComputerName $vmmHostname
If ($vmm -eq $null) {
    $return.Code = 1
    $return.Text = "VMM server '$vmmHostname' cannot be accessed."
    $return
    Exit
}

Get-SCVirtualMachine -Name $hostname
```

I see the following

1. Memory consumption in the client system can continue to grow without ever releasing memory. (Even after the current script finishes executing.)
2. The number of established network connections to the VMM server (observed by running `netstat -an` on the VMM server) also continues to go up.
3. Eventually, new connections take a **very** long time to established (30-60 seconds) or they just stop altogether.

However, after all my research and testing, I see that the following script works fine and both keeps memory consumption low and the number of network connections small (1 or 2). (As a matter of fact, the connection is established, used, and cleaned up fast enough that `netstat` usually does not even show it in the list.)

```
If (-Not(Get-Module -Name VirtualMachineManager)) {
    Import-Module -Name VirtualMachineManager
}

Get-SCVirtualMachine -VMM $vmmHostname -Name $hostname
```

The key, for some unknown reason at this point, seems to be specifying the VMM server on the individual cmdlets as opposed to establishing the connection at the top of the script.

As far as executing the script from C# goes, my Framework 4.5.1 code *currently* looks like this

```
using (var rs = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()) {
    rs.Open();

    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) {
        ps.Runspace = rs;

        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var scriptName = "LabManagement.Scripts.GetVirtualMachineStatus.ps1";

        using (var s = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(scriptName)) {
            using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(s)) {
                var script = reader.ReadToEnd();

                ps.AddScript(script);
            }
        }

        ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("vmmHostname", this.ServerName);
        ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("hostname", hostname);

        var output = ps.Invoke();

        ...
        // process output and errors
        ...

            rs.Close();
        }
        else {
            rs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure if I need to explicitly create/open/close the Runspace object. Originally I was just creating the PowerShell object. (Since a PS script ultimately runs in a RunSpace, part of my memory consumption hunt was testing if not explicitly creating the RunSpace caused it to "stick around" after the PowerShell object was cleaned up.) As a follow up I will be looking to see if this affects code after I apply the cmdlet parameter fix to all my scripts.